# body.replaceText code in Google Apps scripts timing out i cant figure out why

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

Im creating a simple code in scripts thats on a google sheets. is meant to open a template and change values from the template to the value from the google sheets. heres the code extract
`

```
function Create_PDF() {
  
  const PDF_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1slk_E27fP2bLv-sEYTk7kx44iyHCprgk");
  const TEMP_FOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById("1n37Lc4y4yTRnTFnujUYGlyahq70S_N5q");
  const PDF_Template = DriveApp.getFileById("1a0knbNWyC0BRrwvoKseMuYsaqKvEwQULcrZ3Yb18nIk");
  
  const newTempFile = PDF_Template.makeCopy(TEMP_FOLDER);
  const  OpenDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = OpenDoc.getBody();
  
  
  
    body.replaceText("[name]", ['Name'][0])
    body.replaceText("[dob]", ['Date of Birth'][0]);
    body.replaceText("[email]", ['Email'][0]);
    body.replaceText("[phone]", ['Phone number'][0]);
    body.replaceText("[uni]", ['University, major and year of study Your answer'][0]);
    body.replaceText("[school]", ['High school'][0]);
    body.replaceText("[schooldeg]", ['High school degree'][0])
    body.replaceText("[language]", ['Languages'][0]);
    body.replaceText("[exp]", ['Ushering past experience'][0]);
    body.replaceText("[position]", ['Which of these positions fit with your past experience? '][0]);
    body.replaceText("[nightlife]", ['Are you open for nightlife work?'][0]);
  OpenDoc.saveAndClose();
  

  const BLOBPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile =  PDF_folder.createFile(BLOBPDF).setName(['Name'][0]);
  console.log("The file has been created ");
  
  return pdfFile;
}
```

`
this is just timing out. it produces the copy in the temp folder but doesnt create a pdf in the pdf folder

I put the command `console.log("working")` between each `body.replaceText` function. it starts to slow down at schooldeg and timesout at language how can i fix this

Comment: What is the point here: `['Name'][0]` is that same `'Name'`

Comment: Check your executions.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Have you tried to use the debugger?

Comment: How big is the doc?